# Bigcommerce event not getting in webhooks?

Tags: php, webhooks, bigcommerce

How to create the event generate in webhooks?
where in bigCommerce set the target path ?

when i run test.php file 
$url = 'https://hooks-beta.bigcommerce.com';

$fields = array(

```
    "producer"=>"store/b111e",

    "scope"=>"store/customer/updated",

    "deliverymethod"=>"HTTP_POST",

    "destination"=>array(

        "url"=>"http://shopifywebhook.hirevisitingfaculty.com/demo.php"

    ),
```

);

i got result

{
"
client_id":"mwadsdd6srh7",

"created_at":"2013-10-15T09:29:58+00:00",

"deliverymethod":"HTTP_POST","destination":

{"url":"http://shopifywebhook.hirevisitingfaculty.com/demo.php"},

"id":1578,

"is_active":true,

"producer":"store/bewe","scope":"store/customer

/updated","updated_at":"2013-10-15T09:29:58+00:00"}

but this result get when i run my local file not when customer update 
and not getting even customer id ?

Comment: Can you check logging on hirevisitingfacility to see that the inbound calls are firing when you expect? You may need to configure your application to allow cross site posting for demo.php.  Have you checked that your webhook is still active? If the webhook call fails `is_active` will quickly switch to false and you'll need to reactivate it. Hope this helps.

Comment: I wrote up a blog on how I did this in Rails- the process should be very similar for you: http://www.dextropy.com/2014/01/connecting-rails-apps-to-bigcommerce.html